# Fastify fail to serialize response schema when using oneOf / anyOf at top level

Tags: javascript, serialization, jsonschema, fastify

this is my route:

```js
fastify.route({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/foo/:foo_id",
    schema: {
        params: {
            foo_id: { type: "string" },
        },
        response: {
            200: {
                oneOf: [
                    { type: "string" },
                    { type: "number" },
                ],
            },
        },
    },
    handler: fooHandler,
})
```

when I try to start the server I get this error message:

```
{
    "code":"FST_ERR_SCH_SERIALIZATION_BUILD",
    "message":"Failed building the serialization schema for GET: /foo/:foo_id, due to error undefined unsupported",
    "statusCode":500,
    "stack":"FastifyError: Failed building the serialization schema for GET: /foo/:foo_id, due to error undefined unsupported
        at Boot.<anonymous> (/home/fooUser/repo/node_modules/fastify/lib/route.js:280:19)
        at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
        at Boot.emit (events.js:327:22)
        at /home/fooUser/repo/node_modules/avvio/boot.js:153:12
        at /home/fooUser/repo/node_modules/avvio/plugin.js:269:7
        at done (/home/fooUser/repo/node_modules/avvio/plugin.js:201:5)
        at check (/home/fooUser/repo/node_modules/avvio/plugin.js:225:9)
        at internal/process/task_queues.js:153:7
        at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (async_hooks.js:186:9)
        at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (internal/process/task_queues.js:150:8)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)"
}
```

I don't see anything wrong in my schema definition. It seems like it's not working only for the response schema. I tried the same schema for the `body` and for the `foo_id` and it worked properly:

```js
params: {
    foo_id: {
        oneOf: [
            { type: "string" },
            { type: "number" },
        ],
    }
},
body: {
    oneOf: [
        { type: "string" },
        { type: "number" },
    ]
}
```

It is also working when I use `oneOf` inside the response schema but at a nested level, like so:

```js
response: {
    200: {
        type: "object",
        properties: {
            foo: {
                oneOf: [
                    { type: "string" },
                    { type: "number" },
                ],
            }
        }
    },
}
```

I don't see why I can't define multiple schema for an http response, that does not make sense.

Comment: Note that you can also rewrite that schema `{ oneOf: [ { type: "string" }, { type: "number" } ] }` as `{ type: [ "string", "number" ] }`.

Comment: Good to know, thank you, that's a good workaround for that case. Unfortunately, my schema are way more complex objects than what I gave in example, and therefore this workaround won't work. As @ManuelSpigolon suggested, using a custom `serializerCompiler` did the trick for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that [fast-json-stringify](https://github.com/fastify/fast-json-stringify) doesn't support `oneOf` as the root object:

```js
const fastJson = require('fast-json-stringify')

const serial = fastJson({
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    response: {
      oneOf: [
        { type: "string" },
        { type: "number" },
      ],
    }
  }
})

console.log(serial(5));
console.log(serial("5"));
```

So you have a couple of solutions:

1. send a PR to the module to add this feature
2. wrap your plain string/number prop to an object:

```js
fastify.get('/', {
  schema: {
    response: {
      200: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          response: {
            oneOf: [
              { type: "string" },
              { type: "number" },
            ],
          }
        }
      },
    },
  }
},...
```

3. Write a custom serializer for these special cases in your handlers:

```js
const fastify = require('fastify')({ logger: true })
fastify.get('/', {
  serializerCompiler({ schema, method, url, httpStatus }) {
    return (responsePayload) => {
      if (typeof responsePayload === 'string') {
        return `"${responsePayload}"`
      } else {
        return `${responsePayload}`
      }
    }
  },
  schema: {
    response: {
      200: {
        oneOf: [
          { type: "string" },
          { type: "number" },
        ],
      }
    },
  },
  handler: async () => { return Math.random() >= 0.5 ? 5 : '5' }
})
```

Comment: I see, thank you for clarifying! I am still wondering why it didn't yield an error for the body and foo_id schema I gave in example. `oneOf` is at the root for both of them

Comment: Oh I see now, `fast-json-stringify` is only used for the serialization of a response's body